# construct a sequence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $(H_n)$ be a sequence of different finite dimensional complex Hilbert spaces, $A_n \in B(H_n),tr(A_n) \to 0(n \to \infty)$,but the norm of $A_n$ does not converge to 0,where $tr()$ is the standard tracial state.

Can we construct a sequence of operators $(P_n)$ such that each $P_n \in B(H_n)$ , $\|P_n\| \to 0 $and $tr(P_nA_n)$ does not converge to 0?

Comment: What is the connection between your two sentences? You introduce these $A_n$, then never mention them.

Additionally, the norm of a projection is either $0$ or $1$, so this sequence would be exceptionally boring.

Comment: Aweygan,Imade a mistake.I have reedited it

Comment: Is the question about whether this can be done for **some** sequence $(A_n)_n$, or for **any** sequence $(A_n)_n$ on which the trace tends to zero?

Comment: @Angelo Lucia，for some sequence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Take $H_n = \mathbb{R}^2$ for all $n$, and
$$ A_n = \begin{bmatrix}a_n&  0 \\ 0 &-a_n\end{bmatrix} \quad P_n = \begin{bmatrix}b_n&  0 \\ 0 &-b_n\end{bmatrix} $$
where $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ are two sequences we will choose in a second.
Then clearly $\operatorname{tr}(A_n) = 0$ for each $n$, and $||P_n|| = |b_n|$, so if we choose $(b_n)_n$ such that $\lim_{n} |b_n| = 0$ then we satisfy your assumptions.

Now $\operatorname{tr}(P_nA_n) = 2a_n b_n$, so it is enough to choose $a_n = (b_n)^{-1}$ to have $\operatorname{tr}(P_nA_n) = 2$ which clearly does not converge to zero.

Comment: the standard tracial state needs to multiply $1/2$

Comment: If $H_n$ are different,can we have a similar construction?

Comment: I think you need to specify something more concrete than "the $H_n$ are different". You can definitely construct a lot of similar "easy" examples.